# why i cant import pyperclip in pycharm editor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pycharm, pyperclip

using Pycharm,i have a project for saving password in a txt file, it mandatory to use pyperclip module while i have already downloaded it safely from powershell and cmd and it already works for python IDLE and in bash(shell,cmd).

i am already aware that i can do that with python IDLE but its too slow and i cant use other source codes to see what works for me(due to its compiling rule that unless a line is not compiled the other cant be compiled).

[image: Here pycharm gives me error]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/8/12092a393ff0b8dde98e11e41112a5b1-full.jpg))</sub>

[image: IDLE works]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/8/5a325260950f162c7cf56afad927c58c-full.jpg))</sub>

[image: powershell works indeed!]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/8/b381226875f66c06949be7ac258c021a-full.jpg))</sub>

```
 import pyperclip
 pyperclip.copy()
 pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: Is your pycharm correctly Setup. Check if the Interpreter (python.exe) is the same as in powershell. Goto Settings and search `Interpreter` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following:
`1.file`>>>`2.Project`>>>`3.Project Interperter`>>>`4.click on the + button`>>>`5.search "pyperclip"`>>>`6.click on install button`

Answer (score 0):

Now the above one doesn't work, so find/click the following:

[image: settings]

[image: interpreter]

[image: final]

all the above link are images linked to stack overflow, (unable to edit via html)